# Why is My Program not Working

Tags: c++

I am a noob programmer,who just started in C++. I wrote a program, to answer a question. When I try to run it from my cmd.exe, windows tells me "a problem has caused this program to stop working, we'll close the program and notify you when a solution is available".

I have included a link to the well documented source code. Please take a look at the code, and help me out.
link: http://mibpaste.com/ZRevGf

i believe, that figuring out the error, with my code may help several other noob programmers out there, who may use similar methods to mine.

Code from link:

```
 //This is the source code for a puzzle,well kind of that I saw on the internet. I will include the puzzle's question below.
//Well, I commented it so I hope you understand.


//ALAFIN OLUWATOBI 100L DEPARTMENT OF COMPUTER SCIENCE BABCOCK UNIVERSITY.
//Future CEO of VERI Technologies inc.


/*
* In a corridor, there are 100 doors. All the doors are initially closed.
* You walk along the corridor back and forth. As you walk along the corridor, you reverse the state of each door.
* I.e if the door is open, you close it, and if it is closed, you open it.
* You walk along the corrdor, a total of 200 times.
* On your nth trip, You stop at every nth door, that you come across.
* I.e on your first trip, you stop at every door. On your second trip, every second door, on your third trip every third door and so on and so forth
* Write a program to display, the final states of the doors.
*/


#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

inline void inverse(bool args[]); //The prototype of the function. I made the function inline in the declaration, to increase efficiency, ad speed of execution.

bool doors [200]; //Declaring a global array, for the doors.

int main ()
{
    inverse(doors); //A call to the inverse function

    cout << "This is the state of the 100 doors...\n";

    for (int i = 0 ; i<200 ; i++) //Loop, to dis play the final states of the doors.
    {
        cout << "DOOR " << (i+1) << "\t|" << doors[i] << endl;
    }

    cout << "Thank you, for using this program designed by VERI Technologies. :)"; //VERI Technologies, is the name of the I.T company that I hope to establish.

    return 0;
}

void inverse(bool args [])
{
    for (int n = 1 ; n<= 200 ; n++) //This loop, is for the control of every nth trip. It executes 100 times
    {
        if (n%2 != 0) //This is to control the reversal of the doors going forward, I.e on odd numbers
        {
            for (int b = n, a = 1 ; b<=200 ;b = n*++a) //This is the control loop, for every odd trip, going forwards. It executes 100 times
                args [b] = !args[b] ; //The reversal operation. It reverses the boolean value of the door.
        }
/*
* The two variables, are declared. They will be used in controlling the program. b represents the number of the door to be operated on.
* a is a variable, which we shall use to control the value of b.
* n remains constant for the duration, of the loop, as does (200-n)
* the pre increment of a {++a} multiplied by n or (200-n) is used to calculate the value of b in the update.
* Thus, we have the scenario, of b increasing in multiples of n. Achieving what is desired for the program. Through this construct, only every nth door is considered.
*/

        else if((n%2) == 0) //This is to control the reversal of the doors going backwards, I.e on even numbers
        {
            for (int b = (200-n), a = 1 ; b>=1 ; b = (200-n)*++a) //This is the control loop for every even trip, going backwards. It executes 100 times.
                args [b] = !args[b] ; //The reversal operation. It reverses the boolean value of the door.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And the debugger shows nothing? Try debugging it. You should get a detailed exception then.

Comment: It seems like your program crashes. Run in a debugger to locate where the crash happens, the debugger will stop at the location of the crash and let you examine values of variables as well as examine the function call stack and also let you walk up the call stack if it's not in your code.

Comment: But if I were you I would start looking in the `inverse` function where you read and write out of bounds of the `doors` array. Reading and writing out of bounds of an array leads to *undefined behavior* and is a common cause of crashes.

Comment: Your debugger may not be installed correctly if Windows doesn't offer to invoke it when your program crashes.

Comment: If you ever get a notification from windows on an available solution, please lets us know. I am really curious

Comment: I don't understand most of the terms you used. I'll use the debugger, my dev C++/Code Blocks should have 1. Please can you explain what you mean by "out of bounds"

Comment: I have come up with a solution.     I'm convinced that it was the out-of-bounds error, that you mentioned Joachim. i documented my source code for the solution in more detail, please read it and comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***EUREKA!!!!!!***

I finally came up with a working solution. No more errors. I'm calling it version 2.0.0
I've uploaded it online, and here's the link

[version 2.0.0] http://mibpaste.com/3NADgl

All that's left is to go to excel, and derive the final states of the door and be sure, that it's working perfectly. Please take a look at my solution, and comment on any error that I may have made, or any way you think that I may optimize the code.I thank you for your help, it allowed me to redesign a working solution to the program. I'm sstarting to think that an Out-of-bounds error, might have caused my version 1 to crash, but the logic was flawed, anyway, so I'm scrapping it.

This is ths code:

```
/**********************************************************************************************
200 DOOR PROGRAM
Version 2.0.0
Author: Alafin OluwaTobi Department of Computer Science, Babcock University
New Additions: I redrew, the algorithm, to geneate a more logically viable solution,
I additionally, expanded the size of the array, to prevent a potential out of bounds error.
**********************************************************************************************/

//Hello. This a program,I've written to solve a fun mental problem.
//I'll include a full explanation of the problem, below.

/**********************************************************************************************
    *You are in a Hallway, filled with 200 doors . 
    *ALL the doors are initially closed . 
    *You walk along the corridor, *BACK* and *FORTH* reversing the state of every door which you stop at .
    *I.e if it is open, you close it .
    *If it is closed,  you open it .
    *On every nth trip, you stop at every nth door .
    *I.e on your first trip, you stop at every door. On your second trip every second door, On your third trip every third door, etc .

*Write a program to display the final state of the doors .
**********************************************************************************************/

/**********************************************************************************************
                                        SOLUTION
    *NOTE: on even trips, your coming back, while on odd trips your going forwards .
    *2 Imaginary doors, door 0 and 201, delimit the corridor .
    *On odd trips, the doors stopped at will be (0+n) doors .
    *I.e you will be counting forward, in (0+n) e.g say, n = 5: 5, 10, 15, 20, 25
    *On even trips, the doors stopped at will be (201-n) doors.
    *I.e you will be counting backwards in (201-n) say n = 4: 197, 193, 189, 185, 181
**********************************************************************************************/

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>  //Including the basic libraries

bool HALLWAY [202] ; 
/*
    *Declaring the array, for the Hallway, as global in order to initialise all the elements at zero.
    *In addition,the size is set at 202 to make provision for the delimiting imaginary doors, 
    *This also serves to prevent potential out of bound errors, that may occur, in the use of thefor looplater on.
*/

inline void inverse (bool args []) ;
/*
    *Prototyping the function, which will be used to reverse the states of the door.
    *The function, has been declared as inline in order to allow faster compilation, and generate a faster executable program.
*/

using namespace std ;   //Using the standard namespace

int main ()
{
    inverse (HALLWAY) ; //Calling the inverse function, to act on the Hallway, reversing the doors.

    cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t200 DOOR TABLE\n" ;

    for(int i = 1 ; i <= 200 ; i++ )
    //A loop to display the states of the doors.
    {
        if (HALLWAY [i] == 0) 
        //The if construct allows us to print out the state of the door as closed, when the corresponding element of the Array has a value of zero.
        {
            cout << "DOOR " << i << " is\tCLOSED" << endl ;
            for (int z = 0 ; z <= 300 ; z++)
                cout << "_" ;
            cout << "\n" ;
        }

        else if (HALLWAY [i] == 1)
        //The else if construct allows us to print out the state of the door as open, when the corresponding element of the Array has a value of one.
        {
            cout << "DOOR " << i << " is\tOPEN" << endl ;
            for (int z = 0 ; z <= 300 ; z++)
                cout << "_" ;
            cout << "\n" ;
        }
    } 

return 0 ; //Returns the value of zero, to show that the program executed properly
}

void inverse (bool args[])`

{

    for ( int n = 1; n <= 200 ; n++)

    //This loop, is to control the individual trips, i.e trip 1, 2, 3, etc..

    {

        if (n%2 == 0)
        //This if construct, is to ensure that on even numbers(i,e n%2 = 0), that you are coming down the hallway and counting backwards
    {
            for (int b = (201-n) ; b <= 200 && b >= 1 ; b -= n)
            /*
                *This loop, is for the doors that you stop at on your nth trip. 
                *The door is represented by the variable b.
                *Because you are coming back, b will be reducing proportionally, in n.
                *The Starting value for b on your nth trip, will be (201-n)
                * {b -= n} takes care of this. On the second turn for example. First value of b will be 199, 197, 195, 193, ..., 1
            */
                args [b] = !(args [b]) ;
                //This is the actual reversal operation, which reverses the state of the door.
       }

        else if (n%2 != 0)
        //This else if construct, is to ensure that on odd numbers(i.e n%2 != 0), that you are going up the hallway and counting forwards
        {
            for (int b = n ; b <= 200 && b >= 1 ; b += n)
            /*
                *This loop, is for the doors that you stop at on your nth trip. 
                *The door is represented by the variable b.
                *Because you are going forwards, b will be increasing proportionally, in n.
                *The starting value of b will be (0+n) whch is equal to n
                * {b += n} takes care of this. On the third turn for example. First value of b will be 3, 6, 9, 12, ...., 198
            */
                args [b] = !(args [b]) ;
                //This is the actual reversal operation, which reverses the state of the door
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the exception is due to the line:

```
for (int b = (200 - n), a = 1; b >= 1; b = (200 - n)*++a)
```

When the exception occurs the following values are assigned to the variables:

```
b = 3366
n = 2
a = 17
```

From what I can see, b is calculated by (200 - n) * a.

If we substitute the values given we have: 198 * 17

This gives us the value of 3366 which is beyond the index of doors and throws the exception when the line

```
args[b] = !args[b];
```

is executed.

I have created the following solution that should provide the desired results if you wish to use it.

```
void inverse(bool args[])
{

    //n represents what trip you are taking down the hallway
    //i.e. n = 1 is the first trip, n = 2 the second, and so on
    for (int n = 1; n <= 200; n++){

        //We are on trip n, so now we must change the state of all the doors for the trip
        //The current door is represented by i
        //i.e. i = 1 is the first door, i = 2 the second, and so on
        for (int i = 1; i <= 200; i++){

            //If the current door mod the trip is 0 then we must change the state of the door
            //Only the nth door will be changed which occurs when i mod n equals 0
            //We modify the state of doors[i - 1] as the array of doors is 0 - 199 but we are counting doors from 1 to 200
            //So door 1 mod trip 1 will equal 0 so we must change the state of door 1, which is really doors[0]
            if (i % n == 0){
                args[i - 1] = !args[i - 1];
            }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll apply your fix to my ode and see what happens. I'll also try and create alternate solutions. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: I was trying to run a mental simulation, of your code, I noticed that it seems to assume that we're only going forward. When you reach trip 12, for example your coming **back** down the hallway. you would stop first at door. 188. _188%12 = 8_ That does, not flow in accordance with your theory. I've not yet applied it to my code. Can you try and work that factor into your solution.

Comment: ** On ODD trips** you are going up the hallway, starting at an imaginary door zero, your counting upwards from the door zero.           **On EVEN trips** You are counting downwards starting from another imaginary door 201.

Comment: so, _Therefore, on the fourth trip you will stop at door 197 **197%12 = 5**_ .This voids my previous statement, and means, that the solution, I devised does not work properly as I assumed coming down, that you'll start from door 200. Please, try and maybe rework your mod solution. It's a much shorter way, of representing the solution. I'll eventually use excel, to simulate everything so that I know the final states of the doors.

Comment: I'm going back to the drawing board for this program, I actually designed the problem as a practice question for my class mates to play around with. I'll redesign the program, and re-upload the final source code as well, as the final output that I will generate with excel. I don't know macro programming, so I'll create 200 sheets in my workbook, one for every trip. **Thank you for all, your assistance, I really appreciate it!!!!**

Comment: I actually derived this problem from the basic _"100 door problem"_, I added more doors and created a situation, in which you go back, and forth, because I felt it as more realistic and because I felt it'll make for better programming practice.

Comment: Ah I see. I over looked the comment of "back and forth". I assumed that you were walking along the hallway from start to finish on each trip. I see you have created a working solution for the problem now. I would take a similar approach to your solution and use the 2 nested loops with n%2. I would recommend using some constant values or even sizeof(doors) to remove any magic numbers you have, such as the 200 value for the length of doors. This will allow you to change the solution later on with minimal effort.

Comment: Thank you, will do.    I may later on expand it to a 1000 doors or use the construct for other purposes. It was really just meant to be a mental challenge though, to test my logical thinking abilities in C++